# Sql query Where clause filter on code number how to get all record without filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to get data status wise as shown in my query,

```
select  Zipcode,
(CASE pobox
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Available'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Reserved' 
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Assigned'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Closed'
END) as ' Status'
from custom_pobox  
where pobox=@Status
```

Suppose @status = 0 or 1 or 2 any value

but we have values from 0 to 4 in database i want to show all data if person select all from dropdown

then how will i change this query ?

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: Please explain what the acpected results

Comment: Do you mean how to filter by **list of statuses** or how to filter **by specific status OR to get all if no status specified**?

Comment: yes if status 1 give availabe if 2 return Reserved but for all there is no option in database it is hard code in dropdown "ALL" so how i will return all record with any status

Comment: `WHERE pobox=@Status OR @Status is NULL`

Comment: but staus is not null in data base it has value 1,2,3,4

Comment: in Dropdown "ALL" has 0 value

Comment: Which means you need those rows that match `@Status` value (which would be 1, 2, 3, 4) **OR** all rows in case when... `@Status` has a value... that represents the case when in dropdown `ALL` was chosen... which is...

Comment: I tried it is not returning any record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pass 'ALL' if person select all from dropdown and write query like below:    
       select  Zipcode, (CASE pobox
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Available'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Reserved' 
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Assigned'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Closed'
END) as ' Status'
from custom_pobox  
where CASE WHEN @Status <> 'ALL' THEN pobox=@Status ELSE 1=1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all rows your where clause should have

```
where (@status <> 0  AND pobox = @Status) OR (@status = 0 AND 1=1)
```

However, the second *OR* has some redundant filter that should with only `@status= 0`

```
where (@status <> 0  AND pobox = @Status) OR (@status = 0)
```

Comment: first where clause keep on running took so long eve n then it id not return return record

Comment: Same thing happening on both where clauses

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Zipcode, (CASE pobox
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Available'
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Reserved' 
   WHEN 3 THEN 'Assigned'
   WHEN 4 THEN 'Closed'
END) as ' Status'
FROM custom_pobox  
WHERE  Status IN( CASE WHEN @ALL <> 1 THEN (SELCECT CASE pobox
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Available'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Reserved' 
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Assigned'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Closed'
END) FROM CUSTOM_POBOX) ELSE @STATUS END)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. When posting an answer, please add an explanation aside of what your code does, and why it solves the question.